# Why do people not used walking on flat ice mostly fall backward when trying to?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, friction, everyday-life

It's my experience that most people (including myself) fall backward on their behind when trying to learn to walk forward on flat ice and fall forward when trying to run on it. When walking or running (in the now "normal" way: heel first, ball of the foot last, contrary to the aesthetic walking of a ballet dancer and the same we do when walking backward; in fact, the more Natural way to walk is like the ballet dancer does; see the picture below; only with the advent of shoes, especially the modern back shock-absorbing shoes; just try running while putting the front part of your feet first on the ground; feels pretty good!) on a flat non-slippery underground you mostly fall forward and mostly after tumbling (tripping sounds a bit inappropriate in this case). By the way, by walking and running I mean(in the now "normal" way: heel first, ball of the foot last, contrary to the aesthetic walking of a ballet dancer and the same we do when walking backward. In fact, the more Natural way to walk (which is now used to walk as silently as possible) is like the ballet dancer does (see the picture below). Only with the advent of shoes, especially the modern back shock-absorbing shoes we changed our walk. Just try running while putting the front part of your feet first on the ground. Feels pretty good! But let stick to the modern way.

[image]

In can understand why, when walking on high friction underground you mostly fall forward after tumbling. For example, bumping with one foot against a curb you didn't see causes a torque (the force of which grips my foot in backward direction) making my center of mass rotating forward around my foot whereafter gravity makes me fall.

When walking on flat ice, only slipping is involved though, without obstacles your feet can bump against. Of course, there has to be some friction (and there **is** some friction, though little) because without friction walking or running would be impossible.

Now when you are an experienced ice walker, suppose your mass rests on your whole left foot, and the ice gives just enough friction not to slip (let's say in any fall of the normal walking on ice). Then you give your right foot forward motion. This forward motion is what gives you a forward motion in combination with the left foot that stays put but "rolls" over the ice and pushes you forward. (the movement of you right feet gives the left foot a backward force on the ice, which propels you forward. Meanwhile, the left foot changes from staying flat on the ice to standing on the front feet and when the heel of your right leg touches the ice it "rolls" along and your whole mass rests now on your right feet, after which the left leg starts moving and the cycle is complete. Nothing different from normal walking on a rough underground.

But why do people learning to walk on the ice fall so often backward, one of their legs moving upwards in a forward direction? Where can't the friction stop the slipping?
Of course, they also fall forwards but this is mostly the case when they try to run on the ice.

Comment: I doubt your claim. I've seen people (including myself) slip all sorts of ways and directions.

Comment: That's why I wrote **mostly**.

Comment: I still doubt that. Is there any data showing slipping backwards is more likely than slipping some other way?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Why did you edited my question so much?

Comment: @descheleschilder to fix the grammar

Comment: @AaronStevens No, which I said in my question. It's based on my experience, and my experience doesn't lie.

Comment: Because your feet stick out to the front of you (and somewhat to the sides.)

Comment: *...and my experience doesn't lie.* If that was the case then pretty much all of modern physics should not be real.

Comment: Why should that be the case?

Comment: What are the reasons to suggest to close this question?  Because I include dreams in it. There exists in science the well know Kekule's dream. https://web.chemdoodle.com/kekules-dream/

Comment: @descheleschilder I personally voted to close because the premise seemed extremely flawed.  Most falling I've seen occurs in plenty of different directions.

Comment: @AaronStevens Don't you think the opposite would be the case?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is not theoretical question about physics as much as biomechanical question about technique of walking.

When I run during winter, I always fell forward (assuming there is no slope). That is because I am putting my legs on the ground with backward motion to use the force to accelerate. So when they slip, they go backward, while my body center goes still forward.

A lot of people during walking are putting their legs on the ground with forward motion, so when they slip, the legs go forward faster than their body center and they fall on their backs. This is mostly because nowadays we learned to walk through our heels instead of toes as a consequence of wearing shoes.

Comment: A very good answer indeed! Though I doubt if wearing shoes changes the way people put their feet on what is below them while walking. Why should that be?

Comment: Because of the adoption of padding on the heel of shoes. It allows for an unnatural amount of pressure on the heel without discomfort. Since falling on your heel requires less effort from the rest of your legs, this is the way people end up walking since the shoe will protect them from this discomfort.

Comment: @descheleschilder Actually, this is a well known problem with modern running shoes. People who run with bare feet will NOT slam their heels into the ground because it hurts. The moment they put shoes on, they then put the weight on their heels, which is very damaging because the force is bypassing the feet and ankle's absorption abilities and goes up your leg and into your knees. You have no shock absorption past the heel unless you consciously keep your legs bent, but you'll become super tired very quickly.

Comment: I understand. This means that people (mainly women) walking on high-heeled and pointy heels will hit the underground with much higher pressure while walking on slippers are much more close to barefoot (natural) walking.

Comment: It even became evident to me in a dream. I can't exactly remember **why** it became more evident anymore, but I'm sure I know **why** at the moment of waking why it was clearer to me. Which is easily forgotten after having a dream, but ** for sure** I had that dream (or saw that dream)! I didn't forget **that**. Who, else than I can disprove that I had (seen) it!. You just have to put a little trust in me.

Comment: Umm, this is a physics site, so stuff revealed in dreams is not a valid source. Or was it peer-reviewed?

Comment: I was under the impression that walking has always involved stepping down in front of you, heel first, for as long as we have been walking on two feet. I didn't know that that was a shoe thing. Running is, of course, a different story.

Comment: @Arthur well i am no expert in walking techniques, but try stepping heel first barefoot on rocky terrain...

Comment: @Umaxo Sure, but for the first couple hundred millennia since we climbed down from the trees, we didn't live primarily on rocky terrain, did we?

Comment: @Arthur I do not now where we lived. I used rocky terrain as an extreme. Even in forest there is a lot of branches on the ground, small rocks etc., that make stepping on it heel first with nonnegligible impact quite unpleasant.

Answer (score 6):

[image: our feet]

This is how our legs look. When we are standing our weight is balanced by our foot and heel, but we have an extended foot area which can produce torque if needed(in case we are about to fall forward) while no such support is present while we are falling backwards as the heel right on top of which our center of mass lie is the very end and any torque produced by gravity while tilting backwards can not be countered normally and we fall.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me:

When you are walking, and you suddenly feel a foot slipping, and you feel you are in danger of falling forward, you have a shot at catching yourself by kicking a leg forward. Automatically you kick out the leg that isn't bearing weight. Kicking out one leg is a reflex that can be executed very fast, I think. You may fall sideways instead, but I think you can almost always catch your self from falling forward.

Conversely, I think that at the instant you become aware you've started falling backwards it's already too late. Kicking out a leg backwards is much harder, and you can't reach as far.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that should be asked is: "**Why should I fall in the first place?**" The answer being that there was (almost) no force (here static friction) to stop the relative motion between your feet and the ground. Now when you move your feet forward your upper body moves backward (so as to conserve the angular momentum) now since (almost) no external force acts on your body to generate the torque and hence give you some forward angular momentum. Therefore your body continues to move backward and hence falls.

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515428/238497) I found a somewhat similar question on Physics.SE.

Comment: @descheleschilder sorry but I can't comprehend what you are trying to convey?

Comment: I'm really sorry for you that I've changed the MUA-answer to it, but it truly became evident to me in a dream!(!) that the most-voted answer came the closest to being true, so why shouldn't I have changed that button?

Comment: To say I'm sorry!

Comment: @descheleschilder Oh! Then it's OK. I answered the question with a particular case of falling backwards in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

When we walk, rather start to walk we apply force on the ground in backward direction so the floor by Newton's 3rd law applies an equal force in the forward direction to keep one moving as one moves , to keep one from  falling the body applies a torque in the opposite direction to keep you from falling but as you enter a slippery area the torque by friction reduces but if the torque applied by the body before is not reduced, that leads one to fall in the direction in which the body applies the torque, the converse may also be true if the friction applies more torque one may fall in the opposite direction, Thus it depends based on which case you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there is plenty of sound physics in the other answers, I'd like to offer a linguistic alternative. We mostly fall backwards when we *slip* and we mostly fall forwards when we *trip*. These are convenient words that have evolved to describe different mechanisms of humans falling. Slipping is generally where your foot slides from under you, something which is more likely to happen with weight on the back of your foot as discussed in other answers and normally results in landing on your backside.

So in summary you could argue that we slip backwards almost by definition.

Comment: I'll edit, again...